# Issue with Google Scripts Time-Based Trigger in Sheets addon always Failing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm having an issues with a "Sheets Addon" i am working on. I know how to create triggers in a normal script, but what I'm trying to do is create a trigger within an Addon that will call back to a function within that same addon. I want this to be a timed based trigger, every 1 or 2 hrs as the options.

If I create the trigger via sheets scripts, it all works fine, but using the same exact code for the addon.. it fails 100% of the time, but with no specific error, or at least not that i can get to easily.

I'm assuming there is something different to be add to the code to make a new trigger code work within an addon, but not sure what it is. any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 12/4/2019::
example snippet... if i place this into the sheets script, and run it (from the sheet and not from the addon) it works fine. The trigger gets added and calls to the function with no issues. However when i run it from the sheet via the addon, the trigger still gets created but error our when processing.

```
function testCreateTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('testRunTrigger')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(1)
      .create();
}
```

One thing i'm noticing is that the Trigger for the sheet (non-addon) is created with Project name, Deployment, Event, Function ... all populated, but when i run it via the addon, the Deployment is blank.

Also installed the google salesforce addon which has a schedule feature which adds as a trigger, but that addon somehow creates the trigger with a "Blank" value for Project, Deployment, and Function ..but still knows what function within the addon/script to call to process. I think that's what I'm missing, how to create a trigger, from a function, within an addon.

Comment: Using and testing triggers for Add-ons can be tricky. Are you creating the time-based trigger manually? This is not possible for Editor Add-ons. Authorization requirements are likely to create issues. Consult the following link for more information and restrictions related to triggers in add-ons: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers To give you a more specific answer, please provide more information about your Add-on and trigger, a simplified code snippet reproducing the issue would be helpful.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I updated the details to include what you are asking because adding code snippets to the comments here doesn't seem very friendly. let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: How is your function testCreateTrigger() called? within an `onOpen()` function? And what does the function `testRunTrigger()` do? Will the trigger fail to run if you simplify the content of `testRunTrigger()`  to make sure you do not run into authorization issues?